# How to mark as read-only the last row of a DataGridView component?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm displaying the total sum of each column in last row of a `DataGridview` component. But when I click on any cell of last row in `DataGridView`, the values suddenly disappear (i. e. Sum). I use this one line code but it didn't work for me.

`datagridview1.Rows[datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1].Readonly = true;`

So help me how can I solve it

Comment: Is allowusertoaddrows true? if so it creates a new empty last row, filled with nulls.

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution that works for me and I hope it will work for you:

1. In the `DataGridView` properties, set the `AllowUserToAddRows` property to `false`;
2. Use the code line you had specified in the question.